# Create a table of logistic regression results in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, logistic-regression

I would like to create a regression table in `R Markdown` that includes the exponentiated coefficients, exponentiated upper and lower 95% confidence intervals and p-value for each variable in a logistic regression model.

````
```{r}
#basic table
  library(knitr)
  x1 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
  x2 <- rpois(100,5)
  y1 <- rbinom(100,1,0.33)
  df <- data.frame(x1,x2,y1)
  modelx <- glm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = df ,family = "binomial")
  kable(summary(modelx)$coef)

#maneuvers to obtain OR and 95% CI
  orx <- exp(c(OR = coef(modelx), confint(modelx)))
  kable(orx)
```
````

I've tried as above, which creates the values, but loses the labels and general `kable`-friendly form. I have tried directly replacing the exponentiated coefficients into the `glm` object `modelx`. However, this object cannot easily hold the 95% CI.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this task without manually building the table in `tables` or other `kable`-friendly package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process requires transforming the `summary(modelx)` to a `data.frame`, carry out the necessary calculations while adding results to the `data.frame` and finally porting to `kable` with `kableExtra` options to finish the formatting.

````
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
#basic table
  library(knitr)
  library(kableExtra)
  x1 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
  x2 <- rpois(100,5)
  y1 <- rbinom(100,1,0.33)
  df <- data.frame(x1,x2,y1)
  modelx <- glm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = df ,family = "binomial")
  tableit <- data.frame(summary(modelx)$coef)
  tableit$OR <- exp(tableit$Estimate)
  tableit$LCL <- exp(tableit$Estimate - tableit$Std..Error * 1.96 )
  tableit$UCL <- exp(tableit$Estimate + tableit$Std..Error * 1.96 )
  tableit$`p-value` <- tableit$Pr...z..
  tableit <- tableit[c(5,6,7,8)]
  kable(tableit, digits = 2, align = rep('c',4 )) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F)
```
````